# Why is the group of symmetries of a rectangular prism isomorphic to $D_4 \oplus Z_2$?

Tags: group-isomorphism, rectangles, direct-product

I see how a rectangular prism is made up of two squares and four rectangles.

Each square is isomorphic to $D_4$. Isn't a rectangle isomorphic to $D_2$ because there are two rotations (0 degrees and 90 degrees) and two reflections (horizontal and vertical axis)?

Also, since there are two squares and four rectangles, do we have to use this fact anywhere?

Comment: How do you define isomorphism between polygons and groups? ​ ​

Comment: You mean *the group of symmetries of a rectangular prism*. You should edit. :)

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm not sure. I can't seem to find that in my textbook, do you happen to have a link to something I could read? I'm having trouble finding information on that.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you! i edited the title of my post

Comment: How does every symmetry of the square turn into a symmetry of the prism? (This accounts for the subgroup $D_4$, which is the symmetry group of the square.) Now, what extra symmetry is there of this 3-D figure you've not accounted for so far? (Most of the symmetries of the rectangle you were thinking of have already shown up.) Can you show this symmetry commutes with those in the $D_4$ subgroup?

Comment: @TedShifrin Does $Z_2$ turn every symmetry of the square into a symmetry of the prism? There's extra symmetries when the whole figure reflects over the z axis?

Comment: No, you have to figure out how the symmetries of the square turn into symmetries of the prism (you won't be able to do reflections across planes with rotations). There's an additional one coming from the whole figure that is not yet accounted for. Where is your $z$-axis?

Comment: @TedShifrin The longitudinal axis is the y axis. I don't really understand how the symmetries of the square turn into symmetries of the prism. Is this other one that isn't accounted for if you had the prism on a table, with one of the rectangle faces down, and spun it 180 degrees?

Comment: That will work (or 90º or 270º). But you can also reflect (not by a motion in $\Bbb R^3$) to switch pairs of edges of the square(s). ... But you need to think about exchanging the squares.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, so exchanging the squares, would that be a type of permutation?

Comment: Well, sure. But think about how to achieve it with a symmetry (rotation or reflection) in $\Bbb R^3$. Then try to look at why you need only an extra $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: I"m having trouble understanding what $Z_2$ does to it. I wrote out $D_4 \oplus Z_2 = {(R_0, 0), (R_{90}, 0), (R_{180}, 0), (R_{270}, 0), (V, 0), (H,0), (D, 0), (D', 0), (R_0, 1), (R_{90}, 1), (R_{180}, 1), (R_{270}, 1), (V, 1), (H,1), (D, 1), (D', 1)}$ I'm not sure what this means though